# How to set customization filter in cakephp pagination

Tags: html, cakephp

I have write code in controller for pagination and list the product categories all are working fine. i have product category filter. filter is also working fine. Now Pagination limit is 5. I seach Apple Product category there is 15 record is coming. when i click secong page in pagination that page will be refreshed so filter not applied and total record is coming.

```
    $user_roles = $this->Role->find("all")->toArray();
    $searchParams = $this->request->data();
    $conditions = array();
    if(!empty($searchParams)) {
        if(!empty($searchParams['first_name'])) {
           $conditions['firstname like'] = trim("%".$searchParams['first_name']."%", " ");
        }

        if(!empty($searchParams['status'])) {
            $conditions['status'] = $searchParams['status'];
        }
        if(!empty($searchParams['role'])) {
            $conditions['role'] = $searchParams['role'];
        }

        if(!empty($searchParams['status'])) {
            $conditions['status'] = trim($searchParams['status'], " ");
        }
    }
    try {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users->find("all")->where(array('role NOT IN'=> ['director'], $conditions)));
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {

    }
    $this->set(compact('users', 'searchParams', 'user_roles'));
```

Comment: post your template file as well

Comment: Use this and read it's documentation https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter form method must be "get" not "post" then you will have filters set on each page refresh. And you will need to change this line

```
$searchParams = $this->request->data();
```

to this:

```
$searchParams = $this->request->getQuery();
```